# Angular change ID based on Scroll Position

Tags: angularjs, scroll

I have a question concerning scroll positions/behavior in AngularJS.

I have a fixed sidebar with div classes with text (three items no menu) and would like to achieve an opacity change on those classes based upon the current scroll position of the window.

For example, if I reach

```
<div class="example1">
```

My goal would be to have the opacity changed on the first item in the sidebar which for example would be called

```
<div class="sidebar1">
```

I've found plugins via github for this, but would like to achieve this purely with angular. Does anybody know how to approach this best to avoid messy code and a bloated application?

Answer (score 1):

There's a module you can get via npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-inview named ngInView. It will let you call an event whenever an item comes into view. This should get you going in the right direction.

Also on github at: https://github.com/iamssurya/angular-inview